# can i change the style of my button using his name taken from array?

Tags: javascript, html

i have this array with my buttons being declared out of an array:

```
var buttons = [
  'button1',
  'button2',
  'button3',
  'button4',
  'button5',
  'button6',
];
let button = document.querySelector(".buttonstart");
let maintext = document.querySelector(".elementialText");
let button1 = document.querySelector(".button1");
let button2 = document.querySelector(".button2");
let button3 = document.querySelector(".button3");
let button4 = document.querySelector(".button4");
let buttoncontinue = document.querySelector(".buttoncontinue");
let button5 = document.querySelector('.button5');
let button6 = document.querySelector('.button6');
```

tried to change style of my buttons like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    (buttons[i]).style.display = 'block';
  };
```

but it's not working. can i use .style.display using my array parameters?

Comment: why not use `querySelector`? I.e. ``document.querySelector(`.${buttons[i]}`).style.display = 'block';``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't define the variable buttons as Node array. Try this:

```
let button = document.querySelector(".buttonstart");
let maintext = document.querySelector(".elementialText");
let button1 = document.querySelector(".button1");
let button2 = document.querySelector(".button2");
let button3 = document.querySelector(".button3");
let button4 = document.querySelector(".button4");
let buttoncontinue = document.querySelector(".buttoncontinue");
let button5 = document.querySelector('.button5');
let button6 = document.querySelector('.button6');

var buttons = [
  button1,
  button2,
  button3,
  button4,
  button5,
  button6,
];

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```